# Alter existing dynamic route to a different route with a User Parameter

Tags: 8, routes

In the Open Social distro when you click on an author link it takes you to `/user/[uid]/stream`. This path is a path to a view. The social_user.routing.yml file includes:

```
  path: '/user/{user}/home'
  defaults:
    _entity_view: 'user.stream'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\social_user\Controller\SocialUserController::accessUsersPages'
```

In Open Social, the path `'user/{user}/home'` redirects to `'user/{user}/stream'` and I would like to change it so that it redirects to `'/user/{user}/activity'`. This path uses a custom view I have made.

In my custom module I have created a `wfto_main.services.yml` file containing:

```
  wfto_main.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\wfto_main\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

And then a `RouteSubscriber.php` file at `wfto_main/src/Routing` containing:

```
  namespace Drupal\wfto_main\Routing;

  use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
  use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

  /**
   * Listens to the dynamic route events.
   */
  class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
      if ($route = $collection->get('social_user.user_home')) {
        $route->setPath('/user/{user}/activity');
        //$route->setDefault('_entity_view','teaser');
        $route->setDefault('_controller', '\Drupal\wfto_main\Controller\WFTOUserController::alter_edit_route');
      }
    }
  }
```

And finally a `WFTOUserController.php` file at `wfto_main/src/Controller` containing:

```
  namespace Drupal\wfto_main\Controller;

  use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

  class WFTOUserController extends ControllerBase {

    /**
     * Function to redirect the edit route to custom route
     */
    public function alter_edit_route() {
      $uid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('user');
      return $this->redirect('social_user.user_home', ['user' => $uid]);
    }
  }
```

However, this code is not having any affect and the author link is still redirecting to `'/user/{user}/stream'`. I am a little bit unsure about my code in the WFTOUserController.php file and also if I need to set any more defaults in the RouteSubscriber.php file?